# Need to use Apache Kafka in my React-Native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've used [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/)  in my project and need it integrated inside a react-native app which is also part of the project. Basically, my server is a Kafka producer and the app needs to listen to topics and be a consumer.

At first, I tried using this npm package. https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node. 

But this package relies on core modules of nodejs that are not part of the React Native bundle. Is there any other way so as I could communicate using Kafka inside a React Native app?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [DeepstreamIO](https://deepstream.io/tutorials/integrations/msg-kafka/).

It's a real-time socket server that integrates well with both React-Native and Kafka. It can use Kafka as a message broker to communicate messages between distributed Deepstream nodes and push messages to other subscribed clients. They are open source so you can configure their connectors to your specific needs.

Comment: Wow! I just read your comment. I should tell you I had done the exact same thing and followed the exact same solution. It worked like a charm, the only thing I didn't like about Deepstream was non persistence of commits which was in Kafka. Marking this answer as correct anyway.

Comment: btw, link is down

Comment: Probably outdated as there are no mentions of "kafka" in its site's search.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution would be to put the Kafka cluster behind a simple REST API. Using a library like [kafka-rest](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) could be an easy way to connect your React Native app using the built in `fetch` function. You could go a step further and try to integrate the [kafka-rest-node](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-node) client into your React Native app; a cursory overview of the repo doesn't lead to any core Node dependencies.

Another method, one which would allow for "live" updates, might consist of putting Kafka behind a web server that converts the Kafka stream into a WebSocket connection. Libraries such as [kafka-websocket](https://github.com/b/kafka-websocket) allow clients to both consume and produce, whereas a more simple library like Microsoft's [kafka-proxy-ws](https://github.com/Microsoft/kafka-proxy-ws) only allows for consuming messages.

It's worth noting that mobile clients don't always work well with streaming data, and you'd be advised to test your WebSocket-based implementation on a variety of uncertain network conditions (latency, dropped signals, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! This is certainly doable with a REST wrapper for Kafka. But in that case too I need to constantly keep making a Rest call to the Rest wrapper server from my react native app. (or you could say, polling) However, this would beat the purpose of Kafka as there won't be any Pub/Sub architecture. I don't want my app to keep making one request after another. 
`kafka-rest-node` uses `kafka-native` internally so we can't use it either.

Comment: @MustansirZia I've updated the answer to reflect your concerns.

Comment: Thank You for your interest! Putting a broker in between was just too much work and unnecessary complexity. I went for DeepStream as it was just to cater to my needs well.